# I have a data frame with date column but when running the R script on sql server it's not able to run and gives me this error

Tags: sql, r, ssms

EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified type 'date' for column #4 in result set #1, and the corresponding type sent at run time was 'float'; there is no conversion between the two types.

Comment: please add  the relevant part of your script and an excerpt of the data you're trying to write. you can use `dput(head(mydata, 10))` to get the data to put into your question.

Comment: This sounds like you are running R Services inside MS SQL Server. Please post full stored procedure containing R code.

Comment: This was a data type conversion issue and by changing the date format to POSIXCT by using as.POSIXct.Date() it worked.